# Is there a formula to count dates as the approach?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

I created a sheet to track projects that my team is working on. it contains it has a few columns which are conditionally formatted. One of those columns is for the date equipment needs to ship out to projects, some of the dates are out a few weeks and I want to include a formula at the top of the list which returns the total number projects which are upcoming within 7 to 10 days.
I tried several of the Date & Time formulas but they require a start date be entered which means that a start date would constantly be changed. Can =COUNTIF or a different formula be used return only the number of pending projects based on them starting either 7 or 10 days away until the date passes?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an auxiliary column with formula:

```
=A2-TODAY()
```

[image]

Then you can use COUNTIFS function to get the result you need to count >=7 and <=10:

```
=COUNTIFS(C2:C9,">=7",C2:C9,"<=10")
```

[image]

If you want to use Conditional Formatting to format the cells for date, you can enter this formula as a rule:

```
=AND(A2-TODAY()>=7,A2-TODAY()<=10)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks to Thomas Mockler & Lee, both answers were exactly what I was needing. They worked great!

Answer (score 0):

I would have a cell that has today's date: =TODAY()

I would make a column that refers to the project dates minus that cell with today's date. Dates are actually stored by excel as numbers, which allows them to be used in formulas.

Then I would do a =COUNTIFS on that column that I made. =COUNTIFS let you define multiple criteria.

Here's and example:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gwx7.png]

((There's probably a more elegant/efficient solution. I'll let you know if I think of it.))